# How to save the previous record after reinstall iOS objective-c ?

Tags: ios

I am working on iOS app saving flight paths using objective-C programming. When it comes to reinstalling the app, all data is cleared. Would you please tell me how to fetch the saved record back ?

The below is my working.

```
#import "DBManager.h"


@implementation DBManager


static DBManager  *sharedInstance = nil;

+ (DBManager *) sharedInstance
{
    if (sharedInstance == nil)
        sharedInstance = [[super alloc] init];

    return sharedInstance;
}

- (id) init
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[self getDbFilePath]]) //if the sqlite database file  does not exist
        {
            NSArray *arrayTable =  [[NSArray alloc ]initWithObjects: @"taskpoint" ,  @"journey" , @"commandsent" ,nil ];

            for(int  i = 0 ; i < (int)[arrayTable count] ; i++) {
                [self createTable:[self getDbFilePath]  table: (NSString *)[arrayTable objectAtIndex:i] ];
            }

        }else{
            NSLog(@" all tables exist");
        }
    }
    return self;
}


-(NSString *) getDbFilePath
{
    NSString * docsPath= NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
    return [docsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.db"];
}

-(int) createTable:(NSString*) filePath table:(NSString*) tablename
{
    sqlite3* db = NULL;
    int rc=0;
    rc = sqlite3_open([filePath UTF8String], &db);
    if (SQLITE_OK != rc)
    {
        sqlite3_close(db);
        NSLog(@"Failed to open db connection");
    }
    else
    {
       if([tablename isEqualToString:@"taskpoint"]){
            char * query ="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS taskpoint ( id INTEGER , mid INTEGER , status INTEGER , alti INTEGER , speed INTEGER , ht INTEGER , df INT , dcw INT, desp TEXT , lat REAL , long REAL   )";
            char * errMsg;
            rc = sqlite3_exec(db, query,NULL,NULL,&errMsg);
            if(SQLITE_OK != rc)
            {
                NSLog(@"Failed to create taskpoint  list rc:%d, msg=%s",rc,errMsg);
            }
            sqlite3_close(db);
        }else if([tablename isEqualToString:@"journey"]){
            char * query ="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS journey ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  , desp TEXT    )";
            char * errMsg;
            rc = sqlite3_exec(db, query,NULL,NULL,&errMsg);
            if(SQLITE_OK != rc)
            {
                NSLog(@"Failed to create journey list  rc:%d, msg=%s",rc,errMsg);
            }
            sqlite3_close(db);
        }else if([tablename isEqualToString:@"commandsent"]){
            char * query ="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS commandsent ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , desp TEXT    )";
            char * errMsg;
            rc = sqlite3_exec(db, query,NULL,NULL,&errMsg);
            if(SQLITE_OK != rc)
            {
                NSLog(@"Failed to create table list  rc:%d, msg=%s",rc,errMsg);
            }
            sqlite3_close(db);
        }

    }
    return rc;
}
```

Comment: Is it device specific? As in, will the data you want to save be unique for each user?

Comment: nope, but I would like to store in local instead of server - client

Answer (score 0):

Please try one of them

- Backup database to iCloud
- You have a server side to handle
- Save data in keychain

Comment: how to work for Backup database to iCloud or Save data in keychain ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Core Data Migration
   There are different ways to do it depends on the complexity of the migration

1. Light weight migration
2. complex migration
3. custom migration

Comment: Do you mean using Core Data instead of SQLITE  ?

Comment: Yes, using Core data